# cicontext drawImage:inRect:fromRect crashes in ios6

Tags: ios, memory-management, opengl-es, core-image, glkit

I'm trying to get an video from camera and render it using CoreImage and OpenGL.
When I'm running it I see my picture on screen as I expect and then I get EXEC_BAD_ACCESS.
I'm using ARC. iOS6 Beta1.
Please help me to fix it.

Update: it works in 5.1 but crashes in 6.0.
I've raised All Exception Breakpoint but I only see that EXEC_BAD_ACESS happens in presentRendedBuffer > gpus_ReturnGuiltyForHardwareRestart

Update2: I've removed camera-related code and it's still crashes.

Update 3: When I commented out glClearColor & glClear commands my app stopped crashing. But I still want to know how to use OpenGL together with Core Image simultaneously.

my new code as simple as:

```
@interface MGViewController () {
...
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) EAGLContext *glcontext;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CIContext *cicontext;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CIImage *ciimage;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.glcontext = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];

    if (!self.glcontext) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to create ES context");
    } else {
        self.cicontext = [CIContext contextWithEAGLContext:self.glcontext];

        if (!self.cicontext){
            NSLog(@"Failed to create CI context");
        }
    }

    GLKView *view = (GLKView *)self.view;
    view.context = self.glcontext;
    view.drawableDepthFormat = GLKViewDrawableDepthFormat24;

    self.ciimage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"roomphoto" withExtension:@"png"]];
}

- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
{

        glClearColor(0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        [self.cicontext drawImage:self.ciimage
                           inRect:self.ciimage.extent
                         fromRect:self.ciimage.extent];
}
```

This code works on iPhone & iPad 6.0 simulator; crashes with EXEC_BAD_ACCESS on iPad2 iOS 6.0 Beta2; and it gives me just green screen on iPad 1 & iPhone 4S iOS 5.1.1 with messages in the console:

```
Invalid shader program, probably due to exceeding hardware resourcesCould not load the kernel!Could not load the kernel! ...
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: does it crash on iOS5.x?

Comment: No, it works on my iPhone with 5.1.1 but fails on my iPad with 6.0.

Last time i've received message in console:

Cannot render using GPU because process in in background.
Unable to fall back to CPU when rendering to screen - rendering may fail!
(lldb)

Could it be due to drawImage:inRect:fromRect is async in iOS6 but sync in iOS5?

Comment: Hit Command+6. Click little plus button on bottom left corner. Select "Add Exception Breakpoint". Click done. Run your application again. You'll see exact location of the exception. Report it here to get better feedback.

Comment: Exeption doesn't fire up, just EXEC_BAD_ACESS HAPPENS in presentRendedBuffer > gpus_ReturnGuiltyForHardwareRestart

Answer (score 2):

Finally I've managed to stop app from crashing.
I just added **glFlush()** between gl commands and [cicontext drawImage...] command.

```
- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
{

        glClearColor(0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glFlush();

        [self.cicontext drawImage:self.ciimage
                           inRect:self.ciimage.extent
                         fromRect:self.ciimage.extent];
}
```

The result isn't perfect: I can see some jittering etc. but at least it works.
I would appreciate a detail answer why, though.

Comment: Given that this works when you run it on iOS 5.x, but crashed on an iOS 6.0 beta, I think that it's pretty clear this is a beta bug. I recommend filing a bug report at https://bugreport.apple.com/ , ideally with a test project that reproduces this. That should help the Core Image team fix this before proper release.

Comment: That figures. Talking with them, they've made some significant changes to Core Image for 6.0, and I've seen this in my own tests, so it's not surprising that one or two things might break in the beta.

Answer (score 2):

drawImage:inRect:fromRect is asynchronous in iOS 6.